# How to use paste command recursively in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, paste

I have a paste command in my script. But it is not giving my desired output. my datafile is

```
file.txt
1
3
5
4
```

my shell script is

```
f1=file.txt
for j in 1..12
do
awk '{printf ("%.1f\n", $1+'$j');}' $f1 > $j_$f1
paste $j_$f1 > ofile.txt  # ofile.txt is a new empty file
done
```

This script gives output as

```
ofile.txt
2
4
6
5
3
5
7
6
.
.
```

My desired output as

```
ofile.txt
2  3  4  5  6 ... 13
4  5  6  7  8 ... 15
6  7  8  9  10 .. 17
5  6  7  8  9 ... 16
```

I also want to do for the following script

```
bonus_company1=10
bonus_company2=25
bonus_company3=50
declare var=("company1" "company2" "company3")
for k in var{[@]}
do for j in jan..dec
   do if [ $j == "jan" ] || [ $j == "may" ] || [ $j == "sep" ]; then
      awk '{printf ("%.1f\n", $1+ '$bonus_$k');}' $f1 > $k_$j_$f1
      elif [ $j -ne "jan" ] && [ $j -ne "may" ] && [ $j -ne "sep" ]; then
      awk '{printf ("%.1f\n", $1+5);}' $f1 > $k_$j_$f1
      fi
      paste $k_$j_$f1 > $k.txt  # $k.txt is a new empty file
   done
done
```

so I will get 3 different files for three companies. e.g

```
company1.txt
11  6  6  6  11 .....
13  8  8  8  11 .....
15  10 10 10 15 .....
14  9  9  9  14 .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest doing the whole thing in awk, rather than using a shell loop:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=12; ++i) printf "%d%s", $1+i, (i<12?FS:RS)}' "$f1" > output
```

This loop runs for each line of the file and outputs all of the columns, saving the need to use another tool such as `paste`. The ternary operator is used to output a space (`FS`) between each column and a newline (`RS`) at the end of the line.

---

For the second part of your question, you can still do most of the work in awk.

```
declare -A companies
companies=( [company1]=10 [company2]=25 [company3]=50 )
for c in "${companies[@]}"; do
    awk -v bonus="${companies[c]}" '{for (i=1; i<=12; ++i) 
        printf "%d%s", $i+(i==1||i==5||i==9?bonus:5), (i<12?FS:RS)}' "$f1" > "$c.txt"
done
```

I have created an associative array containing each company name and their bonus. The loop goes through each company in the array, passing the bonus to awk as a variable (note that I'm doing this using `-v` rather than using string concatenation). The loop goes from 1 to 12, adding the bonus for months 1, 5 and 9, or 5 otherwise. The name of the company (the key of the shell array) is used for the output file.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean, you should edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: It looks great!! Then is it possible to do when my j is different characters in stead of numbers e.g. for j in {different company names} and my computation is different accordingly e.g. if [a conditon true]; then awk '{printf "%s\n", $1}. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how you could address the second part of your question. I am assuming that you're using a shell that supports associative arrays (e.g. bash), partly because you were using `==` for comparisons in your attempt.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tom. It is excellent. Regarding bash- yes, I use bash shell. May I ask you why it is == (double equal sign) for if command and = (single equal) for awk command. I have not much idea about linux and scripting.

Comment: @Roselover in awk, `==` is used to check for equality and `=` is used for assignment. In the shell, the standard way to check two strings are equal is to use `[ "$str1" = "$str2" ]` but bash also supports the use of `==`, to make it more like most other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand, why are you going in such complicated way. You can do it in a more simpler way:

for 2nd one:

```
for k in var{[@]}
do awk '{printf("%.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f\n", $1+"$bonus_$k", $1+5, $1+5, $1+5, $1+"$bonus_$k", $1+5, $1+5, $1+5, $1+"$bonus_$k", $1+5, $1+5, $1+5);}' file.txt > $k_file.txt
done
```